# CodeSacnner library of cn1 works in Android but crashed in ios without any error message

Tags: codenameone

I use the CodeScanner library of cn1 for QR code scan. This library installs Barcode Scanner + simple for the scanning process and works in Android.
I also build my project for ios. But my program crashes in my iPhone 7 max without any error message when trying to scan QRCode. The library doesn't install any 3rd party for the scanning process in iOS.

```
CodeScanner.getInstance().scanQRCode(new ScanResult() {
   public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {                        

         
  }
    public void scanCanceled() {

    }
    public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {

 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the build hint: `ios.NSCameraUsageDescription` with description of why you need to use the camera.

This should have been added automatically by the simulator and should have been documented. I suggest opening an issue on that [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/).

Comment: I have added this issue.
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3564